# JS close event not working on a page, how to find out the error?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events

A click that is closing a modal outside of this modal is working on codepen but it is not working on my page. Here is the code that is working on codepen:

```
window.addEventListener('click', outsideClick);

function outsideClick(event) {
    if(event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = ('none');
    }
}
```

but something is wrong, it's not working on my page. Just have a look here https://italents.pl. You can't close it when You click out of the modal.  the codepen https://codepen.io/hubkubas/pen/wXpYwy working perfectly. How can I find the problem?

Comment: So if there an error on the console? Is `outsideClick` getting called? Did you debug what `event.target` is? Did you debug what `modal` is? The `console.log()` line is your friend on helping you figure things out.

Comment: if you click outside the modal, how can `event.target == modal` ?

Comment: @JaromandaX that's what I thought too but the modal (or overlay) actually covers the whole screen and I think OP means click outside the inner modal box, which is on the overlay - which OP has called modal.  Hubert - links to codepen must include the code in the question itself

Comment: oh ... does your "modal" cover the whole viewport like it does in that codepen?

Comment: modal (class) is everything like the background and the the modal-content (class) so if You click modal You click out side the modal-content. The code from the code pan is copied into css.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think somehow click event is suppressed on window. Try below code.

document.body.addEventListener('click', outsideClick);

Comment: wow that's it - it's working, You are my hero. Thank You. I have been looking for this solution for two days by myself :)